# How to find the number of nodes at a specific height Binary Search Tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

If we have a binary search tree and we have to find the number of nodes at a user input height?
As the user enter

```
h = 3
```

what will be the number of nodes for this height?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: 0. No nodes have been added by the given code.

Comment: Run `BFS` algorithm starting from the root of tree, and report `h`-th level nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the row with each node, you can run BFS and stop at row h. The root will have h=1, and each of its children will have h=2 and so on. Therefore when you discover nodes with the right row value, you can stop visiting them and simply count them.

Here it is in pseudocode:

count = 0
ENDROW is user-inputted row num
Set the root's rownum to 1 (or 0 if depending on how you're indexing)
Put root on discovered vertices queue
While queue still has elements:
   pop the first vertex (v)
   if v's rownum = ENDROW - 1:
       count += number of children
   else:
       for each child:
          set rownum to v's rownum + 1
          add to discovered vertices queue